# Overlay SVG animation on top of another SVG

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to make a loading screen for my React app but without the high-CPU load of SVG animations. I came across [this article](https://fjorgedigital.com/insights/blog/can-svg-animations-use-less-cpu/) about splitting the static and animated assets into separate SVGs for a performance gain. My app uses MUI but I want the spinner to be loaded before MUI loads to avoid a blank screen, so it must be in JSX only.

I've tried everything I can think of the make it work but can't get the animated SVG to align over the top of the static SVG to create the spinning effect.

```
function StyledProgress({ message }) {
  return (
    <div className="progress-backdrop">
      <svg
        style={{ position: "absolute" }}
        width="48px"
        height="48px"
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
      >
        <circle
          cx="50"
          cy="50"
          fill="none"
          stroke="#bdbdbd"
          stroke-width="8"
          r="36"
          stroke-dasharray="169.64600329384882 58.548667764616276"
        ></circle>
      </svg>
      <svg
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
        width="48px"
        height="48px"
        viewBox="0 0 100 100"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid"
      >
        <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          type="rotate"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          dur="0.9900990099009901s"
          values="0 50 50;360 50 50"
          keyTimes="0;1"
        ></animateTransform>
      </svg>
      <span className="progress-text">{message ? message : "Loading"}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I'm aiming to replicate in JSX:
[Stackblitz - MUI Progress](https://stackblitz.com/edit/6vbwab--run?file=index.js)

What I've tried:
[Stackblitz - my HTML/CSS attempt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rdhvze?file=src/App.js)

Reference article:
https://fjorgedigital.com/insights/blog/can-svg-animations-use-less-cpu/

Comment: I don't think the article reflects how browsers actually work. Regardless any line up issues have you found it actually has any CPU effect.

Comment: Anecdotally, yes. Testing with a low powered macbook from 2103, my CPU fan kicks in after about 30seconds with both elements in one SVG. When I split them it runs without the fan coming on at all.

Comment: And this is consistent over Chrome, Safari and Firefox?

Comment: I have only tried Chrome. When I get it all working in that Stackblitz you can test if you like. I am only building for Chrome .

Comment: Your `<svg>` elements are children of a HTML `<div>`. So if you have alignment issues, they are certainly caused by the CSS you apply. Please include the relevant parts of the stylesheet in your question. In addition, applying a SVG `transform` attribute to a top level `<svg>` element is something that is prone to errors and browser bugs (and wouldn't have worked only a short time ago). Why not go with a CSS `transform` and associated CSS keyframe animation?

Comment: The css is in this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rdhvze?file=src%2Fstyle.css I have tried the keyframes approach but it's still janky and kicks in the CPU fan. This method above is the only method I've tried that doesn't.